# How can you add a loop around gulp.src

Tags: javascript, gulp

I am trying to make gulp search our entire code base for each term in an array. However, when I add a loop around gulp.src I am getting strange results. The code as written loops over all elements in the array first and then starts to output the chunk paths. Anyone know of a way to do this? It's my second day using gulp...

```
var through = require('through2')
gulp.task('searchTranslations', function(options) {

var termsArr = ['action_add_address', 'action_about', 'action_edit_address', 'action_remove', 'action_set_password'];

for (var i = termsArr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    rtn =  gulp.src('./src/**').pipe(through.obj(function(chunk, enc, cb) {
        console.log('chunk', chunk.path) // this should log now
        cb(null, chunk)
    }))
}

return rtn;

});
```

Comment: I end up find a way to do it by storing the file contents in memory and iterating after the gulp.src() but it seems inefficient.

Comment: did you try `gulp-search`?